uniform convergenof this function to 0
I have to show that this function $f_n(x)=n\chi[0,\frac{1}{n}]$ converges unifomly to zero if I am distant from point 0  equivalently $f_n(x)\rightarrow 0 $ on $(\delta,1)$
but when i try to calculate the norm
$\left|f_n(x)\right|=max_{x\in(\delta,1/n)}n=n\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and is not $0$ how can do?

That sequence of functions does not converge uniformly to $0$.

@EthanBolker so it is right what I wrote?

For some $0< \delta < 1$, there exists a large enough natural number $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < \delta$. Moreover, observe that the support of the function $f_n$ is in the interval $(0,\frac{1}{n})$. Therefore for $n>N$, $f_n(x) = 0$ for $x \in (\delta,1)$ .Thus $f_n$ will uniformly converge $0$ on $(\delta,1)$. This sequence of functions is a classic example to show that limits and integrals in general can't be interchanged, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{[0,1]} f_n(x) dx = 1 \ne 0 = \int_{[0,1]} \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n dx,$$  where $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n  = 0$ a.e.

thanks for answering when you say "Thus fn
will uniformly converge" why ? I mean what is wrong in the calculation I made above ?

The sup norm of $f_n$ should be $0$. So, $||f_n|| = \sup_{x \in (\delta,1)} |f_n(x)| = 0$ for $n>N$.

correct me if I am wrong . I first fix my point $x$ in the interval and than for $n>N$ the sup will always be zero  so the norm of my function is zero?

For a fixed $x \in (0,1]$, there will exist a natural number $N_x$ such that $\frac{1}{N_x}<x$, therefore for $n>N_x$, $f_n(x)=0$. We are taking the supremum of the function $f_n$ over the interval $(\delta,1]$ for some fixed $\delta>0$, and for $n>N$, $f_n(x)=0$ for all $x \in (\delta,1)$. Which is why the sup norm is zero.
